# Which line can I start to put my code in, in template for Tizen Native Wearable App (Samsung G3)

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I just started trying to make a Samsung G3 app using Tizen Studio. I'm very new to coding in C. In the template given by Tizen Studio, I'm not sure where I am supposed to start coding/writing my own code.
     For example, if I want to start by creating this sensor:

```
sensor_type_e type = SENSOR_HRM;
sensor_h sensor;

bool supported;
int error = sensor_is_supported(type, &supported);
if (error != SENSOR_ERROR_NONE) {
   dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "sensor_is_supported error: %d", error);
   return;
}

if(supported){
   dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "HRM is%s supported", supported ? "" : " 
   not");
   sprintf(out,"HRM is%s supported", supported ? "" : " not");
   elm_object_text_set(event_label, out);
}
```

Where would I put that in this short template provided to me:

```
#ifndef __basicui_H__
#define __basicui_H__

#include <app.h>
#include <Elementary.h>
#include <system_settings.h>
#include <efl_extension.h>
#include <dlog.h>
#include <sensor.h>

#ifdef  LOG_TAG
#undef  LOG_TAG
#endif
#define LOG_TAG "basicui"

#if !defined(PACKAGE)
#define PACKAGE "org.example.basicui"
#endif

#endif /* __basicui_H__ */
```

Comment: That's not a source code template; that's a header file.

Comment: C is more of an expert tool than a beginner's language. I would strongly recommend learning C basics first before tackling anything as complex as a mobile app.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield you're totally right. I missed the src file completely.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/getting-started/creating-your-first-tizen-wearable-native-application) to create your first Tizen wearable application in Native platform. In this guide everything is described step by step. I think by following this guide, you will be able to learn basic of Tizen Native application.

After getting familiar with Tizen, check the Heart rate sample application. [Here](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications) is a simple tutorial of Heart Rate with source code.

Screenshot from this app is below 
[image]

You may also check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oce-Si88qVE) on YouTube about Tizen Native App Fundamentals.